# When do I have to include things like Java's public static void main

Tags: support, policy, answers

Can someone tell me why sometimes people are including `class C{public static void main(String[]a){...}}` and sometimes that seems to be not necessary?(https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62373/46569)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever submissions are required to be full programs, Java's standard boilerplate code (i.e. `class` and `main`, etc.) is required. When submissions are allowed to be functions, this boilerplate is not required.

Comment: Unless the OP specifies otherwise, I think @AlexA. means.

Comment: @VoteToClose I can't imagine a situation where the OP would require boilerplate for a function (thereby making it a full program) or not require boilerplate for a full program (thereby making it a snippet, which aren't allowed by default).

Comment: You could have a fickle OP :P

Comment: I meant "Unless the OP specifies otherwise, submissions are required to be full programs..." c:

Comment: When it's a function, that doesn't mean just a function body though. So you still need the function header and whatnot, even though you don't need the rest of the boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I actually completely missed the "write a program **or function**"

Comment: @VoteToClose Except that the default is the other way around. If not specified, functions are fine: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/14215