# What's the Java policy with REPL existing?

Tags: discussion, policy, java

An extension of [When do I have to include things like Java's public static void main](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/when-do-i-have-to-include-things-like-javas-public-static-void-main).

Unless you've (probably) been living under a rock, you (probably) know that Java 9 is (probably) going to have a [REPL interpreter](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) ready for use now. This means that all the boilerplate code is no longer necessary, as we no longer need to define that if we're just doing evals in the console.

Therefore, things like this (73 bytes):

```
class M{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(4+3);}}
```

can now be reduced to just 23 bytes:

```
System.out.println(4+3)
```

Or, if weirdly-formatted results are acceptable (3 bytes):

```
4+3
```

In fact, you can [try this here for yourself](http://www.javarepl.com/console.html), and it actually works!

So, with this in mind, this is probably going to change how Java questions are scored. Therefore, we have the issue of whether the site will consider this to be actual Java (maybe these will be filed under Java REPL?), and whether this is an "accepted" shortcut.

So... What will the future of Java mean for PPCG and the scoring of Java posts?

Comment: I guess I live under a rock. :P

Comment: I think this topic is covered by [When is code that requires a REPL acceptable?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7842/12012).