# What are the standard guidelines for calling the function that does whatever the post says?

Tags: discussion

like for languages that need a starting point, like c++, c#, java and kotlin.

I always post my answers in the function form instead of also calling it from the starting point. If we need to actually call it from the starting point, then that's a huge waste of bytes. what are the standard guidelines for that? or say, one could define that function as an extension function rather than a normal function that takes in the input as parameters if it saves bytes, what's the matter for this as well?

Comment: Hi there! The general consensus for including "boilerplate" (that's the starting point you're talking about) is that [you don't need to count it in your score if you are submitting a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7516/78850). You only need boilerplate if you are submitting a full program. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I have to include things like Java's public static void main](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/when-do-i-have-to-include-things-like-javas-public-static-void-main)

Comment: @lyxal yep it exactly does! but what about the extension function part?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by extension function?

Comment: fun `Int.returnOneMore() {return this+1}` and it would be called by `intVariable.returnOneMore()` or `1.returnOneMore()`

Comment: huh, I can't find any existing consensus on extension functions. Guess we'll see

Answer (score -1):

## Extension Functions should be treated as helper functions

That is to say, they shouldn't be the main submission function, but they shouldn't need boilerplate.

For example:

```
Int.returnOneMore() {return this+1}
```

on it's own wouldn't be a valid submission, but:

```
Int.returnOneMore() {return this+1}
fun f(){/* something that calls the defined extension function */}
```

would be.

Comment: is there a consensus on this?

Comment: I don’t see why they should be treated as helpers, they’re just functions with different syntax. (I’ll post an answer to this myself once I’m on my laptop)